# Virtual client/server (like vmware server's console) - Is it possible?

Tags: virtualbox, vmware-server

Is it possible to install a following setup in VirtualBox:

Install a Linux server + VirtualBox OSE.
Install Virtualbox OSE on a windows machine.

Manage the Virtualbox on the linux server using the virtualbox console on the windows machine, as it is possible on vmware server.

Answer (score 0):

Not as such, but you could have a look at [phpVirtualBox](http://code.google.com/p/phpvirtualbox/). This enables you to manage VM's through a web interface.

[image]